# Best way for database design

Tags: database-design

I am trying to find the best solution for my database.

What i have

**Offer**

```
DateOffer                       the date the offer is made
RateId                          foreign key to table with price/tax rates
Hours                           ammount of hours worked
Buissnes (boolean)              is it for a buissnes 
                                (yes tax = WorkTaxBuissnes no = WorkTax)
ExtraHours (boolean)            if extra hours calculate with ExtraHourRate
```

**Rates**

```
RateId
WorkTax 
WorkTaxBuissnes
NormalHourRate
ExtraHourRate
```

You can see that i need to look for the taxes in the other table, is it smarter to get the taxes on index and add the values to the table Offer so i can do everything from the table offer.

I could change Buissnes (offer) to tax, and extrahours (offer) to WorkTax.

The advantage is i dont need to use any join or if check (extrahours yes no ? buissness yes no?).

The disadvantage is i cant to see if it were extra hours, or if i calculated buissnes tax (cause they change) or i could keep them as extra fields.

Can some one give me advice.

Comment: what's so wrong with using JOIN ?

Comment: nothing but to calculate lets say total i have to use ifs (is extrhour or not, is buissnes or not) if i would save it in 1 table i wont need to. but its just a question cause i dont know what the best option is. what the advantages are of my current situation and the disatvantages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution.

I kept the database as it was in my example so i wont have any double data, (2 times the same tax)

But i added a View wich functions as a table but is in fact a query wich runs on the other tables and returns the values wich can be used like a table like select * from myview

Answer (score 1):

**If Rates is an update-able entity then prevent to keep a copy of them in Offers table.**
Consider we have rate-1 (record) in rates table, assume we are going to have 10 Offers (offer-1 ... offer-10) relating to this rate-1.
After insertion of offers we decide to update rate-1 values.
 
***Scenario 1: add the values to the table Offer (de-normalization )*** 
When inserting offer-1, offer-2, ... offer-10 we will keep redundant data from rates inside offers.
After insertion, when update of rate-1 happens,we need to update offer-1 .. offer-10 
At lest 11 updates is needed (1 for rate-1 and 10 for offers) 
Advantage:

- Calculation of offer costs based on rates will be done fast, no need
  to extra joins.

Disadvantage:

- We redundant same data in 10 records.
- We forced 10 extra updates.
- If any update fails we will have inconsistent data

***Scenario 2: Keep rate related values inside Rate table (Normalization)*** 
Disadvantage:

- Calculation of offer costs is based on rates table data, we need an extra join to fetch rates. less performance is gained. that will cost performance loss.

Advantage:

- We keep rate data in one place, we gained consistency.
- When update of rate happens we kept integrity of our data.

A standard database design guidance is that the designer should first create a [fully normalized dsign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) then selective [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) can be performed for performance reasons.

**Normalization** is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency.
**Denormalization** is the process of attempting to optimize the read performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data.

Hint: Programmers building their first database are often primarily concerned with performance. There’s no question that performance is important. A bad design can easily result in database operations that take ten to a hundred times as much time as they should.

Comment: Ok i have normalized it see the current situation, but my question is what are the disadvantages if i adjust it, so i can do all the querys to calculate totals in 1 table without the use of join and cases .

Comment: The rates are changing but every rate is saved so if i insert a new rate it wont update only insert. but the old Offer wont need to update cause it was made when that rate was activ. so we would never need to update the rates in the Offer table in any case

Comment: In the case saving the rates values in Offer table will be the correct way, you MUST save rates values in offer so in case of Rate updates, Offers costs could be calculable correctly.

Comment: Thats what the OfferId was for, the rate wil stay the same for that offer there only is a new offerId for the new offers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong, but in this simple case i see your second option much more efficient even if there are very limited cases of Rates.

Storage Requirements (with very limited number of rates):

1. Date + 2 x 4 bytes + 2 x 1 bytes (if your database supports tinyints) = Date + 10 bytes.
   (i don't add the storage of the rates because i consider they are limited)
2. Date + 5 x 4 bytes (if you can save the rate id) = Date + 20 bytes.

So the space due to this will be less than doubled, but queries will be lot faster in the case there are extra hours involved. Plus you can execute queries based on the rate values directly in one table.

If the space is not an issue, go the second way no doubt.
And if there are many rate cases same thing.

Comment: Space is not an issue.  I doubt there will be anywhere near 100 items, let alone the millions that a modern database can handle.  Go for elegance and efficiency.

Comment: Yes, normalization vs performance. This is a really simple case. If there are no many other things involved and you expect lots of queries, go for notnormalization ^^

Comment: go for normalization in most cases. when performance really becomes an issue then denormalize. A well configured database can handle millions of records with no problem. "pre optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: I agree, but in this specific case i don't see efficiency in using 2 booleans and one int to join just 4 variables (1 new variable to join). Maybe in this case the second option is even more "normalized". Just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 thats exactly the question, i am not sure what the best way is

Comment: Well, when i was considering this i also expected that you had to save those rates per offer for further management, so as @Mohsen Heydari said in the comments of his answer, in that case it becomes almost a must denormalizing from the beginning.